# Best solution for finding duplicates in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, duplicates

For the sake of learning. I found a simple question but I know it has several solution since I want to practice more and find solution for problems using a function or in normal way.

And so the question goes like this

```
Given an array of integers, how do you determine if there are duplicates?

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

And here is my solution:

for **javascript**:

```
 function has_dup(arr){

        for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
            checker = arr[i];
            duplicates = 0;
            for(x=0; x < arr.length; x++ ){

                //if duplicate          
                if(checker == arr[x]){
                    duplicates++;
                }
            }
        }

        //if has duplicate
        if(duplicates > 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }   
    }

//first run
arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
alert(has_dup(arr));

//second run
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3];
alert(has_dup(arr2));
```

and in **PHP**:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,3);

function check_duplicate($arr){
  $duplicates = 0;

  foreach($arr as $index => $value){

    foreach($arr as $i => $ref)
    {
      if($value == $ref){
        $duplicates++;
       }
    }
  }

  return ($duplicates < 1 ? true : false);
}


check_duplicate($arr);
check_duplicate($arr2);
```

Given to this case can you give me your best answer for both languages, you can also comment on what may mistakes that I'm doing here. I might put a bounty on it if there lots of solution

Thanks!

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-49 this is how underscorejs removes repetitive values if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i use in PHP

```
/*
Scope of has_duplicate is to determine whether the passed array has duplicate values or not
@arguments $arr - array to be tested
@returns boolean value true/false
*/

function has_duplicate($arr){
    return (count($arr) > count(array_unique($arr))) ? true: false;
}
```

refer **[array_unique](http://php.net/function.array-unique)** and **[count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)** on official documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) or [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array), methods provided in the PHP framework.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    //If I havent added this value, then add it..
    if(!in_array($value, $newArray)){
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

For javascript [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's take your original ideas and add some efficiency.
Firstly, if you are just trying to figure out if there is at least one duplicate, once you find your first duplicate, you should return true immediately. If you get to the end of the function, you can assume you haven't found any duplicates. Secondly, don't try to check the same elements over and over again. If they did not match the first time, they won't match the second.

For Javascript:

```
function has_dup(arr){
    var arr_len = arr.length;
    for(var i=0; i<arr_len; i++){
        var val = arr[i];
        for(var j=i+1; j<arr_len; j++){
            if(val === arr[j]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And for PHP:

```
function check_duplicates($arr){
    $len = count($arr);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $val = $arr[$i];
        for($j = $i+1; $j<$len; $j++){
            if($val == $arr[$j]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In PHP, you can also build a unique array and check for differences in size:

```
function check_duplicates($arr){
    return count(array_unique($arr)) != count($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP: use array_unique().

```
function check_duplicate($arr) {
    return (count($arr) > count(array_unique($arr)) ? true : false;
}
```

Javascript: As far as I know, there's no short way. Use UnderscoreJS's _.uniq().

```
function has_dup(arr) {
    return (arr.length > _.uniq(arr).length) ? true : false;
}
```